# How do I tell MyPy that a parameter is not optional?

Tags: python, mypy

I have an object `src` and an optional object `dest`. If `dest` is not passed into the function then a new `MyObj` is created and passed to another function.

Using `mypy==0.610` this is giving me:

> error: Argument 2 to "copy_data" has incompatible type "Optional[MyObj]"; expected "MyObj"

How do I tell MyPy that `dest` is not optional in the `copy_data` function?

```
from typing import Optional


class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def new_obj(name):
    # type (str) -> MyObj
    return MyObj(name=name)

def copy_stuff(src, dest=None, fname=None):
    # type: (MyObj, Optional[MyObj], Optional[str]) -> MyObj
    if not dest:
        dest = new_obj(fname)
    my_obj = copy_data(src, dest)
    return my_obj

def copy_data(src, dest):
    # type: (MyObj, MyObj) -> MyObj
    return dest
```

Comment: Does it still raise the error if you create a separate local variable in `copy_stuff` to hold the `MyObj` instance?

Comment: Ah, it's actually happy with `dest = dest or new_obj(fname)`

Comment: This seems to typecheck for me. Could you provide a minimal reproducible sample? What version of mypy are you using?

Comment: @ethanhs I've added an MVE that fails for me on `v0.610`

Comment: Why do you check for ``not dest`` instead of ``dest is not None``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is in `new_obj`. You are missing a colon in the type comment. I figured this out by putting some `reveal_type`s in you MVE:

```
def new_obj(name):
    # type (str) -> MyObj
    #     ^ ERROR is here
    return MyObj(name=name)

def copy_stuff(src, dest=None, fname=None):
    # type: (MyObj, Optional[MyObj], Optional[str]) -> MyObj
    reveal_type(new_obj)  # E: Revealed type is 'def (name: Any) -> Any'
    if not dest:
        reveal_type(dest)  # Optional[MyObj]
        dest = new_obj(fname)
        reveal_type(dest)  # Optional[MyObj]
    my_obj = copy_data(src, dest)
    return my_obj
```

Mypy seems to keep the type `Optional[MyObj]` when assigned from a function returning `Any`. With the type comment fixed, it works as expected.

Comment: That seems to be correct, and definitely fixes the MVE. I still wonder why it works with `dest = dest or new_obj(fname)` though

Comment: Because if `dest` is not `None`, it will evaluate to `dest`, if it is, the first part of the expression evaluates as falsey, so the second part of the expression, `new_obj(fname)`, is passed. Since that has type `Any`, it is accepted.